# Unconditional Variance of Normal RV with mean being a NRV

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am trying to find the variance of $X$ which is defined like this:

$$X \sim N(Y,e)$$

where $Y$ is a normal random variable with the distribution $Y \sim N(a,b)$. $a$,$b$, and $e$ are known constants.

How can I go about doing this? I set up an integral like this to get the pdf of $X$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)\text{ d}y$$

but have no idea how to solve the integral. please help!

Comment: I am not sure if I am defining this correctly. It may have to do with how X depends on Y - as in how many times will you sample Y to define X. I am envisioning that each time you want an observation from X you have to get an observation from Y.

Comment: Here's some sample R code of a simulation of the scenario I am trying to describe:                                                                                                 Y<-rnorm(10000,1,2)
X<-numeric(10000)
for (i in 1:length(X)){
X[i]<-rnorm(1,Y[i],3)
}
> mean(X)
[1] 0.9722372
> sd(X)
[1] 3.592044

Comment: As you can see the mean of X is a, which is to be expected. The Variance of X is greater than e, which makes intuitive sense to me but I just don't know how to solve for the Variance explicitly.. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my question!

The conditional variance formula:

Var(X) = E[Var(X|Y)] + Var(E[X|Y]) = e + b.